# Using DataGridViewRowCollection object in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'd like to use a `DataGridViewRowCollection` in a LINQ expression using extension methods and lambda expressions. Unfortunately, the extension methods are for types `IEnumerable<T>`, which `DataGridViewRowCollection` doesn't implement. The funny thing is, I can use LINQ here with the SQL-like syntax:

```
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> lRows = from DataGridViewRow row in dgvGrid.Rows 
                                     select row;
```

After doing that, I *can* use LINQ extension methods:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow lRow in lRows.Where(row => row.index > 4)) { ... }
```

Is there any way I can convert my `DataGridViewRowCollection` to an `IEnumerable<>` without using that long first statement? The same thing applies to `DataGridViewCellCollection` and `DataGridViewColumnCollection`.

ps. I'm using .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, do this:

```
var rows = yourDataGridViewRowCollection
               .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
               .Where(row => row.index > 4);
```

This uses the [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method:

> The `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)` method
>   enables the standard query operators
>   to be invoked on non-generic
>   collections by supplying the necessary
>   type information. For example,
>   `ArrayList`  does not implement
>   `IEnumerable<T>`, but by calling
>   `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)` on the
>   `ArrayList` object, the standard query
>   operators can then be used to query
>   the sequence.

Comment: For the record, `OfType<TResult>()` is also a viable choice.  The only difference is that `OfType` will discard anything it can't convert, and `Cast` will throw an exception.