# c# some questions about datagridview change backcolor and group result

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, backcolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# change color for a row if its not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621070/c-sharp-change-color-for-a-row-if-its-not-empty)

I have some Values in my Table and I have some questions how to change it:

1.I want to change background if "KundeID" is not empty to violet, I have tried with --->

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row1.Cells[2].Value != null)
    {
        row1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Violet;
    }
    }
```

but it colors all my table

2.I want to have two X's in object 6,

```
object[] o5 = { 6, "XX", "Sprite"+"Jogurt" }; table.Rows.Add(o6);
```

When I have 2 "Produkts" and want to show it in my table, dont know how

My Table:

```
KundeID KundeName Comment        Jogurt Fanta Sprite    

1       Michael   "nichts"         x                  //violet
2       Raj       "Ich bin cool"                      //violet
        Gary      "yahoo"                 x     
        Miky                                     x       
5       MM                                       x    //violet
(6      XX                         x             x)   // Want to do two X's,    violet
```

My Code:

```
       DataTable table = new DataTable("Kunde");

        table.Columns.Add("KundeID", typeof(Int32));
        table.Columns.Add("KundeName", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Produkt", typeof(String));

        DataTable comment = new DataTable("Comment");

        comment.Columns.Add("KundeName", typeof(String));
        comment.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(String));

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("DataSet");

        ds.Tables.Add(table);
        ds.Tables.Add(comment);

        object[] o1 = { 1, "Michael", "Jogurt" };
        object[] o2 = { 2, "Raj" };
        object[] o3 = { null, "Gary", "Fanta" };
        object[] o4 = { null, "Miky", "Sprite" };
        object[] o5 = { 5, "MM", "Sprite" };

        object[] c1 = { "Raj", "Ich bin cool" };
        object[] c2 = { "Gary", "yahoo" };
        object[] c3 = { "Michael", "nichts" };

        table.Rows.Add(o1);
        table.Rows.Add(o2);
        table.Rows.Add(o3);
        table.Rows.Add(o4);
        table.Rows.Add(o5);


        comment.Rows.Add(c1);
        comment.Rows.Add(c2);
        comment.Rows.Add(c3);

        var results = from table1 in table.AsEnumerable()
                      join table2 in comment.AsEnumerable()
                      on table1.Field<string>("KundeName") equals table2.Field<string>("KundeName") into prodGroup
                      from table4 in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                      select new
                      {
                          KundeID = table1.Field<Int32?>("KundeID"),
                          KundeName = table1.Field<String>("KundeName"),
                          Produkt = table1.Field<String>("Produkt"),
                          Comment = table4 != null ? table4.Field<String>("Comment") : null,
                      };
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var result = new DataTable();
        result.Columns.Add("KundeID", typeof(Int32));
        result.Columns.Add("KundeName", typeof(String));
        result.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(String));
        result.Columns.AddRange(
            (from c in
                 (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                  where !r.IsNull("Produkt") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("Produkt"))
                  select r.Field<string>("Produkt")).Distinct()
             select new DataColumn(c, typeof(bool))).ToArray()
        );

        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            var productIndex = result.Columns.IndexOf(r.Produkt);
            var vals = new List<object>() { r.KundeID, r.KundeName, r.Comment };
            for (int i = 3; i < result.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == productIndex)
                {
                    vals.Add(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    vals.Add(false);
                }
            }

            result.LoadDataRow(vals.ToArray(), true);
        }


        dataGridView2.DataSource = result ;

        //Here will change all background to violet, I want just some of them
        //foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView2.Rows)
        //{
        //    if (row1.Cells[2].Value != null)
        //    {
        //        row1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Violet;
        //    }
        //}
    }
```

Comment: How about finishing your last quesiton which was exactly this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621070/c-sharp-change-color-for-a-row-if-its-not-empty

Comment: now i show my code, because i couldnt lose the problem

Comment: You can edit your questions you know - add stuff to them..

Answer (score 0):

For ASPX (Grid): Hook up `OnRowDataBound` to add color to your rows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGridView2" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" />
```

And put this in your Code-Behind file:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[2].Text))
    {
         e.Row.BackColor = Color.Violet;   
    }
}
```

For WINFORMS: Hook up the `DataBindingComplete` event either by attaching the event as below or using the designer:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
```

Then in the handler you have something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle violet = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Clone();
        violet.BackColor = Color.Violet;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (r.Cells[2].Value != null)
            {
                r.DefaultCellStyle = violet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where and how do i find OnRowDataBound?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: i red it but i dont know where to find it in Windows Forms?

Comment: See edited answer for Winforms version.

Comment: i have tried the code you edited but it doesnt change color to violet