# Looping either through DataGridViewRowCollection or DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to loop through DataGridViewRowCollection or DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection (users choice). I don't know how I can do it the simple way. Here is my Code:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

if (dr == DialogResult.No)
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvResult.Rows)
        rows.Add(row);
else if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvResult.SelectedRows)
        rows.Add(row);

int counter = 1;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DataGridViewRowCollection object in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648657/using-datagridviewrowcollection-object-in-linq)

Answer (score 9):

You may need [**Enumerable.Cast**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method.

```
  List<DataGridViewRow> lst = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList();
```

Comment: error converting "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection" to "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow>"

Comment: @it-west.net Don't forget to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file

Answer (score 6):

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = MyDataGridView.SelectedRows;               
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
  DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
  // do something with your DataRow
}
```

Comment: You can also just make changes to the `DataGridViewRow` that will be reflected automatically back to the underlying `DataRow` due to the nature of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple array and use the CopyTo method of both collections...

```
DataGridViewRow[] data;
if (<your condition here>) {
  data=new DataGridViewRow[dvgResult.Rows.Count];
  dvgResult.Rows.CopyTo(data,0);
} else {
  data=new DataGridViewRow[dvgResult.SelectedRows.Count];
  dvgResult.SelectedRows.CopyTo(data,0);
}
//Do whatever you want with 'data', it's a simple array now.
```

Of course they're both System.Windows.Forms.BaseCollection and you may use the methods of BaseCollection, too...

```
BaseCollection data=<your condition>?dvgResults.Rows:dvgResults.SelectedRows;
//Just enumerate through BaseCollection..
```

Comment: DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection does derive from BaseCollection. However, DataGridViewRowCollection does not. [DataGridViewRowCollection on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection?view=netframework-4.8) [DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection?view=netframework-4.8)